# How do you specify multiple columns for the key, as part of a hash subpartition?

Tags: mysql, sql, partitioning, unique-constraint, data-partitioning

I'm creating a table with composite partitioning (`RANGE`, then `HASH`)

My actual table is enormous, so here's a stripped down dummy table that shows the important parts:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

    dtvalue DATETIME NOT NULL, -- Used for RANGE partitions

    v1 INT NOT NULL, -- Used for HASH partitions
    v2 INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_table1 PRIMARY KEY(id),

    CONSTRAINT uk_table1 UNIQUE(v1,v2) -- Unique key for v1 and v2
)
ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
PARTITION BY RANGE(dtvalue)
SUBPARTITION BY HASH(v1,v2) SUBPARTITIONS 32 -- Does this HASH subpartition work?
(PARTITION p20191101 VALUES LESS THAN('2019-11-01'),
 PARTITION p20191102 VALUES LESS THAN('2019-11-02'),
 PARTITION pMax VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE);
```

This table will frequently be joined by `v1` and `v2` combined as a unique identifier, so using both columns for the `HASH` key is critical.

My question is, can you specify multiple columns as part of the `HASH` key?

Or can you specify the unique key itself, for the `HASH` key?
e.g. `SUBPARTITION BY HASH(uk_table1) SUBPARTITIONS 32`

Comment: Don't bother.  Hash partitioning provides no benefit.

Comment: @RickJames While I completely understand your sentiment, considering most general queries would scan *all* hash partitions, rendering the partitions pointless. However, well-structured queries should always include the hash partition key in the `WHERE` and/or `ORDER BY` clauses, reducing the number of partitions that are scanned. Hence the reasoning behind requiring the hash partition key to be part of the primary key as well. I intend to utilize this properly. But yes, in most fast-paced willy-nilly (badly-designed) database scenarios, hash partitioning would certainly do more harm, than good

Comment: Well structured indexes are as fast, or faster, than using partitioning.  Think of it this way:  Picking the partition costs about as much as shrinking the depth of a BTree index.

Comment: @RickJames Interesting. Is your suggestion affected by the size of the tables involved? I'm looking at the potential of billions of rows being added regularly (with any luck, daily) and I don't want the size of my tables to get out of control. I'm using partitions to keep frequently-accessed rows grouped together in a smaller partition, and older less-frequently-accessed rows in the background and out of the way. I'd like to take your challenge, in your comment below - but would we need billions of rows of sample data to make it accurate? That's a lot of disk space for a challenge ...

Comment: Part of the challenge involves my knowing what column(s) indicate "commonly used".  I don't need any data to present my 'solution'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204577/discussion-between-rick-james-and-giffyguy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to rethink your approach concerning partitioning.  MySQL is quite finicky -- so primary keys and unique constraints need to include the partitioning keys.

And, the hash partitioning takes an integer, but has a very limited repertoire of allowed explicit functions.  Happily, you can get around that with a stored generated column.

So, the following accomplishes your stated goal:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

    dtvalue datetime NOT NULL, -- Used for RANGE partitions

    v1 INT NOT NULL, -- Used for HASH partitions
    v2 INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_table1 PRIMARY KEY(id, dtvalue, v1_v2),

    v1_v2 int generated always as (cast(conv(left(md5(concat_ws(':', v1, v2)), 8), 16, 10) as unsigned)) stored
)
ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS (dtvalue)
SUBPARTITION BY HASH (v1_v2) SUBPARTITIONS 32 -- Does this HASH subpartition work?
(PARTITION p20191101 VALUES LESS THAN ('2019-11-01'),
 PARTITION p20191102 VALUES LESS THAN ('2019-11-02'),
 PARTITION pMax VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE);
```

Comment: It's been about a month, but I wanted to come back and say this has been extraordinarily helpful! I've learned a ton about partitioning, because of researching your tip about primary keys and unique constraints. (I certainly did have to *"rethink my approach"*) Because of this, I've been able to build a robust partitioning setup, that minimizes overhead and maximizes benefit. I've built my primary keys around the partitioning config, and structured all my queries/views to utilize the partition keys to scan as few partitions as possible. Thanks so much! (You've answered many of my questions!)

Comment: @Giffyguy - I challenge you to present a `SELECT` and a `CREATE TABLE` that demonstrates the performance benefit of your Hashing.  I will (try to) respond with an equivalent table and query that runs as fast, but without partitioning.  (I will actually be excited if I fail.)

Comment: @RickJames Interesting. See my comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about MYSQL specifically, but in SQL server I utilize concat.

```
select hashbytes('md5', lower(concat(field1, field2, field3))) from tableX
```

Comment: Looks promising. Lemme give this a try, and see if it works. (MySQL is *very* finicky about what functions you are allowed to use ...)

Comment: Yep, same garbage I've been dealing with all week ... `Error Code: 1064. Constant, random or timezone-dependent expressions in (sub)partitioning function are not allowed near 'CONCAT ( v1 , v2 )...'` I've been spoiled by SQL Server ... switching to MySQL has been a nightmare. Riddled with legitimate bugs that are "documented by design" so they don't have to fix them, and seemingly obvious features missing left, right, and center.

Comment: I wish I could help you, my friend - I am not familiar with MySQL at all.